# Утечки памяти при использовании ImageAnalysis.Analyzer в CameraX

Tags: android, утечка-памяти, android-camera

Нашел пример как с помощью imageAnalyzer-а можно получать битмапы с превью камеры (превью не отображается в активити) https://stackoverflow.com/a/56812799/4482107

Проблема в том, что после добавления Analyzer-а стала течь память. Я уже убрал передачу полученной битмапы вовне и все равно память течет. Причем растет Нативная часть, судя по профайлеру. Примерно 150 Мб натекает за пару часов непрерывной работы приложения (FPS на превью выставлен - 3).

```
val analyzerConfig = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder().apply {
    setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
    setTargetResolution(Size(1920, 1080))
}.build()

val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis(analyzerConfig)
val analyzer = ImageAnalysis.Analyzer { image: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int ->

    val yBuffer = image.planes[0].buffer // Y
    val uBuffer = image.planes[1].buffer // U
    val vBuffer = image.planes[2].buffer // V

    val ySize = yBuffer.remaining()
    val uSize = uBuffer.remaining()
    val vSize = vBuffer.remaining()

    val nv21 = ByteArray(ySize + uSize + vSize)

    //U and V are swapped
    yBuffer.get(nv21, 0, ySize)
    vBuffer.get(nv21, ySize, vSize)
    uBuffer.get(nv21, ySize + vSize, uSize)

    val yuvImage = YuvImage(nv21, ImageFormat.NV21, image.width, image.height, null)
    val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.width, yuvImage.height), 70, out)
    val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
    //lastBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.size)
}

imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(executor, analyzer)
```

executor - это MainThread

CameraX - последней версии - alpha06 (изначально все работало на 01 альфе - там точно такая же проблема.)

Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Так же не понимаю как понять что именно течет в Native-памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Текло вот в этих трех строчках:

```
val out = ByteArrayOutputStream()
yuvImage.compressToJpeg(Rect(0, 0, yuvImage.width, yuvImage.height), 70, out)
val imageBytes = out.toByteArray()
```

Решили проблему отказом от использования compressToJpeg.

Использовали вот такой способ преобразования из Image в Bitmap https://stackoverflow.com/a/55544614/4482107